# ASP.NET MVC How to handle dynamic datetime format from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 dwith EF 6 project, I have a database where datetime format is stored as string like "dd-MM-yyyy". User can change this format any time. User will use the given format in the date fields in the view. But when they will post that. Automatically it will bind as a DateTime for that property. I am statically handling it by the following code

```
[DataType(DataType.Time), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? EndingTime { get; set; }

public string EndingTimeValue
{
    get
    {
        return EndingTime.HasValue ? EndingTime.Value.ToString("HH:mm") : string.Empty;
    }

    set
    {
        EndingTime = DateTime.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

but I know it's not a best way to do that. There may need a model binder or filter or any kind of custom attribute. I will be greatly helped if you give me a efficient solution with sample code. Thanks in advance.

NB: I am using razor view engine. and my solution consists of 7 projects. So there is no chance of using Session in  model. Again I have a base repository class for using entity framework.

Comment: Why not format the date format on the View then?

Comment: Yes I have a last option to do that in view. But I have to change a lot of code and I don't feel it's fit for my problem. I would like to have a common place where I will handle it.

Comment: How user changes the format? And were are you storing the new format?

Comment: there is a form where people can select a date time format. It is stored in the database. When user logs in then using his company information the format string is picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many options regarding this problem. Now what I am doing is created an action filter to catch all the **DateTime** and **nullable DateTime** Fields. Here I am providing the binder.

```
public class DateTimeBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);


        DateTime date;
        var displayFormat = SmartSession.DateTimeFormat;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            return date;
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName,"Invalid Format");
        }


        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

in views the code I am formatting the date using same date format.

Answer (score 0):

People usually store the datetime in the database as a datetime.
Then wherever you do a translation from datetime to string that datetime can be displayed in a format that depends on the culture of the viewer.
By doing this you can quickly make a page with datetime formats that will format the datetimes nicely wherever you are.

change the culture you pass to the toString and the format changes.

please see this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info about it.

edit: (see comments below)
anywhere on server:

```
string WhatYouWant = yourTime.ToCustomFormat()
```

and create an extension method for the datetime that gets the format out of the database and returns a string in the correct format.

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string ToCustomFormat(this DateTime yourTime)
        {
                  // Get the following var out of the database
      String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sszzz";

      // Converts the local DateTime to a string 
      // using the custom format string and display.
      String result = yourTime.ToString(format);
      return result;
        }
    }
```

This will allow you to call it anywhere anytime on your server. You can't access the method client side in javascript. I hope this helps.

(To be honest I'm a new developer too and still have a lot to learn ^^)

Comment: That is what I did. but the actual problem is dynamically choosing the format or culture from database. Where should I do that? in model? or in view or controller. I would like to handle it from one place for all the datetime properties.

Comment: hmm, Basically you would need an additional method on your datetimes that checks the database for the culture and returns a string of the datetime in the correct format. Maybe an extension method for this could be the place you want to do this logic? So you could do a `datetime.ToCustomFormat()` Anywhere you need it? (this is server side)

Comment: suppose if I have to post the date as the the custom format, the property is taking the string as default datetime format. How can I resolve it? Am trying it with modelbinder.

Comment: updated answer, I hope it helps. You do not need to do other datetime calculations in the view (javascript) right?

Comment: thank you bro for your effort I am close to a solution on this issue. Soon I will solve the problem.